# how to find a complex integral when the singular point is on the given curve

Tags: contour-integration, complex-analysis

how to evaluate ∮1/(z-2) dz around the square with vertices  2±2i ,-2±2i
the function is not analytic on z=2.but z=2 is on the given curve.so that can't apply cauchy,s integral formula.how can i do this?

Comment: You can't. The integral doesn't actually make sense.

Comment: is that mean no answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

As Ted Shifrin mentions, the integral does not make sense. One could try to make sense of the integral by making the contour take a semi-circular detour around $2$, and taking a limit as the radius of the arc goes to $0$, but this picture is not very interesting: if the pole is inside, you would get $2\pi i$ from Cauchy's integral theorem (depending on the orientation, you might get its negative). If the pole is outside the contour, you would get $0$ also from Cauchy's theorem (if a function is analytic on a simply connected domain, the integral of that function over a simple closed curve in the domain gets you zero).

Answer (score 2):

The original problem is:

\begin{equation}\label{original}\tag{1}
  \oint\limits_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z-2}\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}

Where $\Gamma$ is the following contour:

[image: Original_contour_with_pole_on_the_curve]

From the figure we see that: $\Gamma = \Gamma_1 + \Gamma_2 + \Gamma_3 + \Gamma_4$. And the contour orientation is the standard one: counterclockwise.

As stated before, strictly speaking, there is no solution to this problem.
The fact that the pole lies on $\Gamma$, stops us from modifying it so that the pole is outside.

But let's pretend nothing stops us to modify $\Gamma$ to calculate the integral.
So we modify $\Gamma$ as follows:
[image: Modified_contour_pole_lies_outside]

Where $\Gamma_\epsilon = L_1 + C_\epsilon + L_2 + L_3 + L_4 + L_5$, the and $C_\epsilon$ is the half circle with radius $\epsilon$ and center $z=2$.

In this case, the contour integral over $\Gamma_\epsilon$ is zero:

\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{2}
  \oint\limits_{\Gamma_\epsilon}\frac{1}{z-2}\,\mathrm{d}z = 0
\end{equation}

But let's take a closer look using the segments of $\Gamma_\epsilon$ and letting $\epsilon\rightarrow0$

\begin{eqnarray}\label{modified_expanded}
  \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}
  \oint\limits_{\Gamma_\epsilon}\frac{1}{z-2}\,\mathrm{d}z 
   &=&
  \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} 
  \left(\int\limits_{L_1} + \int\limits_{L_2} + \int\limits_{L_3} 
  +\int\limits_{L_4} + \int\limits_{L_5} 
  +\int\limits_{C_\epsilon}\right)\frac{1}{z-2}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
  &=& \oint\limits_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z-2}\,\mathrm{d}z + 
      \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int\limits_{C_\epsilon}\frac{1}{z-2}\,\mathrm{d}z = 0 \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{eqnarray}

We now parameterize $C_\epsilon : {z = 2 + \epsilon\,e^{i\theta}}$  with $\theta \in [3\pi/2,\pi/2]$, and insert in \ref{3}:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \oint\limits_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z-2}\,\mathrm{d}z 
  &=& 
 -\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int\limits_{C_\epsilon}\frac{1}{z-2}\,\mathrm{d}z
 \\
 &=&-\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int\limits_{3\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}{\epsilon e^{i\theta}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\nonumber\\
  &=& -i
  \int\limits_{3\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\nonumber\\
  &=& -i(\pi/2 - 3\pi/2)\\
  &=& i\pi
\end{eqnarray}

So, if we allow $\Gamma$ to be modified we have the result:
\begin{equation}\label{4}\tag{4}
 \oint\limits_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z-2}\,\mathrm{d}z = i\pi
\end{equation}

This makes completely geometric sense because if the pole were inside $\Gamma$, e.g. $\oint\limits_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z-1}\mathrm{d}\,z$ the result would be $2i\pi$, i.e. if $\Gamma$ encloses totally (half) the pole the result is $2i\pi$ ($i\pi$).

If $\Gamma$ were the circle with radius 2, this would still hold, as the tangent at $z=2$ would still subtend an angle of $\pi$.

On the other hand, if $\Gamma$ were, for example, an equilateral triangle, with one corner at $z=2$, the result would be $i\pi/3$.

Finally, using $C_\epsilon$ "the other way round", would give the same result.
Here Cauchy's integral theorem and the "the other way round integral" would give $2i\pi - i\pi = i\pi$ which is equal to \ref{4}

Answer (score 1):

This is the situation where you can apply the concept Cauchy Principal Value.
[Cauchy Principal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: Indeed, I would say _must_ apply that idea, since other choices are (even more?) _ad_ _hoc_. That is, if this is part of a larger computation, how do we know that averaging (as in @homero's good answer) is correct? Or principal value? A general remark is that principal value has several structural properties which make it "correct". The lucky fact that averaging gives the same answer is ... lucky. :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my first answer IS Cauchy's Principal Value, it has nothing to do with an average. This is a completely geometrical result, it comes from the fact that we are integrating over half a circle.

I'll try to make all the steps, but still skip a few easy ones:

Let $C$ be a square with corners at $\pm2 + i \pm2$.

We want to calculate the  $PV\oint_C\mathrm{d}z/(z-2)$:
(For the parametric contour see my first post, second image.)

\begin{eqnarray}
PV \oint_C \dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-2} &=& \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}
      \left(
      \int_{\theta=3\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{-i\epsilon e^{-i\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta}{(2-\epsilon e^{-i\theta})-2} +
      \right.
      \nonumber\\
      &&
      + \int_{z=-2-2i}^{2-2i}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-2}
      + \int_{z=2-2i}^{2-i\epsilon}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-2}
      + \int_{z=2+i\epsilon}^{2+2i}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-2}
                        \nonumber\\
                        &&\left.
      + \int_{z=2+2i}^{-2+2i}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-2}
                        + \int_{z=-2+2i}^{-2-2i}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-2}
      \right)
      \nonumber\\
     &=&\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow{0^+}}
     \int_{\theta=3\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{-i\epsilon e^{-i\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta}{-\epsilon e^{-i\theta}}
     + PV\oint_{C}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-2}\nonumber\\
     &=&-i \pi + PV\oint_{C}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-2} = 0
\end{eqnarray}

From here is easy to see that: $PV\oint_C\mathrm{d}z/(z-2) = i \pi.$ $\blacksquare$

Now another example, let's calculate the following: $\oint_{C}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-(2+2i)}$ (i.e. the pole is in a corner: one fourth of the circle)

Analagously we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
PV \oint_C \dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-(2+2i)} &=& \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}
      \left(
      \int_{\theta=3\pi/2}^{\pi}\dfrac{-i\epsilon e^{-i\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta}{(2+2i-\epsilon e^{-i\theta})-(2+2i)} +
      \right.
      \nonumber\\
      &&
      + \int_{z=-2-2i}^{2-2i}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-(2+2i)}
      + \int_{z=2-2i}^{2+2i}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-(2+2i)}\nonumber\\
      &&
      \left.
      + \int_{z=2+2i}^{-2+2i}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-(2+2i)}
      + \int_{z=-2+2i}^{-2-2i}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-(2+2i)}
      \right)
      \nonumber\\
     &=&\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow{0^+}}
     \int_{\theta=3\pi/2}^{\pi}\dfrac{-i\epsilon e^{-i\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta}{-\epsilon e^{-i\theta}}
     + PV\oint_{C}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-(2+2i)}\nonumber\\
     &=&-i \pi/2 + PV\oint_{C}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z-(2+2i)} = 0
\end{eqnarray}

NOTE 1:

Note that the limit in $\epsilon$ is from the right, otherwise the parametrization is wrong.

NOTE 2:

Working from first principles (as if we don't know Cauchy's integral theorem), we MUST use the curve where the pole is outside, so that we can use the trivial result that the closed integral is zero.

Cauchy's integral theorem relies heavily on this trivial result, and of course the limit process and the principle of deformation of curves (maybe a few other things but it's been a long time and I can't remember now)

NOTE 3:

Evan's argument is wrong, as he is not taking into account the limiting process.