# Poles on the curve

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Say I have this integral: $$\oint_\gamma f(z)\,{\rm d}z,$$and $f$ has a pole on $\gamma$. I understand that we "cut around" the pole with an arc of radius $\epsilon$ and then make $\epsilon \to 0$. What I can't understand is if there's a difference if we go outside or inside, like:

[image]
From the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493148/how-to-find-a-complex-integral-when-the-singular-point-is-on-the-given-curve) I understand that we'll get different values, but if we stick to the principal value, will it be the same?

Comment: what's a principal value ?

Comment: Assuming that the pole is simple, the value will be the same in both cases. This is because that while the pole is only inside the first contour, the arcs are traversed in opposite directions. And technically the integral only exists as a Cauchy principal value.

Comment: Yes, that was ok. But I don' get something.. Right in the start, you said that the values will be the same. But in the question I linked, they had a simple pole and the values were different..

Comment: Let's say the simple pole is at $z_{0}$. Going around the first contour and then letting $\epsilon \to 0$ you'll end up with $$ \text{PV} \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz + \pi i \, \text{Res}[f(z), z_{0}] = 2 \pi i \, \text{Res}[f(z), z_{0}].$$
Going around the second contour and letting $\epsilon \to 0$ you'll end up with $$\text{PV} \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz - \pi i \, \text{Res}[f(z), z_{0}] = 0.$$

Comment: Of course I'm assuming there aren't other singularities inside or on the contour.

Comment: @Ivo Oh, you meant the principal value for the original integral, with the pole on the contour! That's different. That PV may or may not exist, depending on the order of the pole. If it's a simple pole the PV is $2\pi i/2$ times the residue of $f$ at the pole. That's assuming the original countour is differentiable at the pole, so that in the limit those little arcs are _hall_ circles.

Comment: @Random I don't think either of the integrals in your comment really count as PVs.

Comment: @Ito Edited my answer, now that I understand the question.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'm not sure what you mean.  You yourself refer to it as the Cauchy principal value of the integral in your answer. I was showing that it doesn't matter if the indentation goes inside or outside.

Comment: @Random Sorry. Misread what you wrote. (I read your $PV\int + \pi i Res=2\pi i Res$ as $PV \int=2\pi i Res$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original curve is differentiable at the bad point, and *if* the pole is simple, then the PV is $2\pi i$ times *half* of the residue.

Too  many $\gamma$s. Let's say $\gamma$ is the original contour, with the pole on the curve. Say $\gamma_\epsilon$ is the inner contour in your picture. And let's write $$\gamma_\epsilon=\gamma_\epsilon'+\gamma_\epsilon'',$$where $\gamma_\epsilon'$ is the original contour with that little bit near the pole omitted, and $\gamma_\epsilon''$ is the circular arc.

So the PV is $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon'}f(z)\,dz$$by definition (assuming I finally understand the question). Cauchy's Theorem says this is $$-\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon''}f(z)\,dz.$$

The point to the differentiability of the original curve is that the opening of the circular arc $\gamma_\epsilon''$ tends to $\pi$ as $\epsilon\to0$. So what you need is this:

Lemma. Say $f$ has a simple pole at the origin with residue $c$. Suppose $a<b$, and for $r>0$ define an arc $\gamma_r:[a,b]\to C$ by $\gamma_r(t)=re^{it}.$ Then $$\lim_{r\to0}\int_{\gamma_r}f(z)\,dz=(b-a)ic.$$

Proof. Write $f(z)=\frac cz+g(z)$, where $g$ is continuous at the origin. The integral of $g$ tends to $0$ as $r\to0$, and you simply calculate that the integral of $c/z$ is $(b-a)ic$ for every $r$.

Comment: Yes, but it is not clear to me if I can do whatever of the ways I put above. Outside or inside, does it matter?

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain what the question is, but I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, you can do it either way. For this comment I'm going to assume the residue is $1$, and also that $2\pi i=1$, heh. In Random's last comment he gave two equations (i) $PV+1/2=1$, (ii) $PV-1/2=0$. My post amounts to an excruciatingly detailed explanation of where (ii) comes from, using the inner contour. If you do what I did but using the outer contour you get (i); the integral over the whole thing changes, the sign of something changes, and with either argument you get $PV=1/2$.

Comment: It's kind of pretty - the PV is exactly the average of the integral over the inner contour and the integral over the outer contour. Another version of the same prettinness: Say $f$ is regular except for a simple pole at $1$. Say $F(r)$ is the integral of $f$ over the circle with center $0$ and radius $r$, taking the PV when $r=1$. Then $F(r)=0$ for $r<1$, $F(r)=2\pi i Res$ for $r>1$, and then $F(1)$ is the average of the left limit and the right limit.

Comment: About the PV being the average, nice, that hit home, thanks! I see, this is very pretty. I just wanted to confirm one last thing. If I understand the notations correctly, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) defines the PV as being the integral over the outer contour (the blue one, in my picture up there), but that doesn't seems right.

Comment: I think possibly you're misreading the wikipedia article. They have a curve $L$, and they say $L(\epsilon)$ is the part of $L$ at distance greater than $\epsilon$ from the bad point, then they say the PV is the limit of the integral over $L(\epsilon)$. In particular their $L(\epsilon)$ does not contain that circular arc! Seems to me their $L(\epsilon)$ is the same as my $\gamma_\epsilon'$, making their definition of the PV the same as what I said.

Comment: Oops, you got a lot of circles in that picture. Seems to me their $L(\epsilon)$ is not that blue arc, their $L(\epsilon)$ is the _large_ arc in your pictures (the intersection of the two pictures).

Comment: Ah, I think I finally got it now. Using the notation in my picture, $\gamma_\epsilon'$ is the arc from C to D, counterclockwise. And $\gamma_\epsilon''$ is the arc from D to C (the small one), also counterclockwise. Is that right? If this is it, then everything is wrapped neatly.

Comment: Yes I think you got it. But the details are off. I was talking about the inner contour - if you're meaning to use the same notation as in my post then $\gamma_\epsilon'$ is the large arc from $E$ to $F$, and $\gamma_\epsilon''$ is the small arc from $F$ to $E$. Like I said, you could revise my argument to use the outer contour instead, and if you were doing _that_ then things would be exactly as you say. (More or less, I reserve the right to be off by $-1$ in comments...)

Comment: We agree with $\gamma_\epsilon'$ then. When you say "small arc" from $F$ to $E$ you mean the red one?

Comment: Yes. (Why the heck won't they let me just say yes? Not enough characters...)

Comment: Thanks for the help and patience. (I'll teach a little hack, don't abuse it, though. Use `${}{}{}{}{}$` to fill the blank space haha)

Comment: ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I feel so evil... thanks.