# Evaluate $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^2 -\frac{3}{2}z + 1} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Evaluate :

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^2 -\frac{3}{2}z + 1} dz$$

Using residue method :

$$z=\frac{3}{4} \pm i \frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}$$

The problem is the two roots on the boundary $|z|=1$

Comment: As the roots are on the contour, the integral diverges.

Comment: Your integral is not well defined. However, in such cases one can use the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332746/poles-on-the-curve), especially [the answer of David C. Ullrich](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1332855) which applies in your case since your poles are simple and the circle is differentiable at any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As stated in the comments, the integral $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^2-\frac32 z+1}\,dz$ is not defined.

However, we can define the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral as the limit

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\left(\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^2-\frac32 z+1}\,dz\right)&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{C_\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^2-\frac32 z+1}\,dz\tag 1
\end{align}$$

where $C_\epsilon$ is the contour $|z|=1$, $\arg(z)\notin (\pm \arctan(\sqrt{7}/3)-\epsilon,\pm \arctan(\sqrt{7}/3)+\epsilon)$. That is to say that $C_\epsilon$ excludes the poles of the integrand.

---

We can evaluate the limit in $(1)$ by using Cauchy's Integral Theorem.  We close the contour $C_\epsilon$ with contours that are circular arcs around the poles such that neither pole is enclosed.

As $\epsilon\to 0^+$ of the integration of the arc around the pole at $z=\frac34+i\frac{\sqrt 7}{4}$ can be easily evaluated using the parametric description $z=\frac34+i\frac{\sqrt 7}{4}+2\sin(\epsilon/2)e^{i\phi}$, $\pi/2 +\epsilon<\phi<3\pi/2-\epsilon$.  Proceeding we have

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\pi/2 +\epsilon}^{3\pi/2-\epsilon}\frac{i}{2i\frac{\sqrt 7}{4}+2\sin(\epsilon/2)e^{i\phi}}\,d\phi=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 7}$$

Similarly, for the integration of the arc around the pole at $z=\frac34-i\frac{\sqrt 7}{4}$ we find

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\pi/2 +\epsilon}^{3\pi/2-\epsilon}\frac{i}{-2i\frac{\sqrt 7}{4}+2\sin(\epsilon/2)e^{i\phi}}\,d\phi=-\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 7}$$

Obviously, since the sum of the residues is zero, then we find

> $$\text{PV}\left(\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^2-\frac32 z+1}\,dz\right)=0 \tag 2$$

---

Another interpretation is to take the average of $\oint_{|z|=1+\epsilon}\frac{1}{z^2-\frac32 z+1}\,dz$ and $\oint_{|z|=1-\epsilon}\frac{1}{z^2-\frac32 z+1}\,dz$ and then take the limit as $\epsilon\to 0^+$.

Since the contour $|z|=1-\epsilon$ encloses neither pole, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that

$$\oint_{|z|=1-\epsilon}\frac{1}{z^2-\frac32 z+1}\,dz=0 \tag 3$$

And since the contour $|z|=1+\epsilon$ encloses both poles we find from the reside theorem that

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=1\epsilon}\frac{1}{z^2-\frac32 z+1}\,dz&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^2-\frac32 z+1}, z=\frac34\pm i \frac{\sqrt 7}{4}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{1}{2i\frac{\sqrt 7}{4}}+\frac{1}{-2i\frac{\sqrt 7}{4}}\right)\\\\
&=0\tag 4
\end{align}$$

The average of $(3)$ and $(4)$ is also $0$ and we find

> $$\text{PV}\left(\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^2-\frac32 z+1}\,dz\right)=0 \tag 5$$

And we see that $(5)$ agrees with $(2)$, as expected!

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I have final exam after two hours .

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And best of luck o nba your exam.